# VBA Datediff function is not working properly

Tags: vba, date, excel

The datediff function doesnt return correct values. I just wanna know the difference of days between  months for ex : 1/03/2014 (starting date ) and 30/03/2014 ( end date)

My tested Code:

```
Dim date1 as date

dim date2 as date

dim test as long

date1 = "1/03/2014"

date2 = "30/03/2014"

test = datediff("d", date1 , date2)

msgbox test
```

The above code returns 86 n, not 29
but it works if i put 1/01/2014 ( starting date ) and 30/01/2014( end date) , the result is 29 days as expected.

how do i get the correct value ( in this case (march) , 29 days)?

Comment: there are [tons of examples on SO how and when to use DateDiff](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+datediff)

Answer (score 2):

use

`DateSerial(2014, 3,1)` and `DateSerial(2014, 3,30)`

to set the dates. By using strings as you do, the strings are interpreted as dates and the 1st of March is interpreted as the 3th of January. The month and day are switched.

Following up on your remark, a simple convert to use with your textbox without any validity tests:

```
strDate = "1/30/2014" 'as an example of the value coming from your TextBox
dateParts = split(strDate, "/") 'returns the date parts an array (zero based)

date1 = dateSerial(datePart(2), datePart(1), datePart(0))
```

Comment: The thing is , i want to transfer the value of a textbox to the datediff function .

Comment: @Feris Tjuanda See the simple conversion to get the date sepcified in your format to a real date. Not that no checking is done whatsoever to check if it is a valid date.

Comment: Thanks for the respond guys , I fixed this with using the format() function and set the variable date1 and date2 to "DD/MM/YY" and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Strings and allow VBA to try to interpret them as a date - use DateSerial and be specific:

```
date1 = DateSerial(2014, 3, 1)

date2 = DateSerial(2014, 3, 30)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try This:

```
Dim date1 as date

dim date2 as date

dim test as long

date1 = "1/03/2014"

date2 = "30/03/2014"

test = datediff("y", date1 , date2)

msgbox test
```

Comment: I am sorry but this is not the answer to the question. You seem to be returning the difference in years and that's totally not what the OP is asking for and describing the problem to be.